# How do I run fsck manually?

Tags: fsck

How do I run fsck manually after I get this notification?

```
/dev/nvmeOn1p5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENTCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY 
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/nvmeOn1p5 requires a manual fsck
```

Answer (score 1):

At the prompt, type:

```
fsck /dev/nvmeOn1p5
```

And hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.